# Apache Spark: Infinite Loop when Running Job Remotely from IDE

Tags: java, apache-spark, ide, remote-access

I have a **apache spark** standalone cluster and I want to run spark's job on it from **remote** computer via **IDE** (Eclipse or IntelliJ). When I create a jar file and send it to master and run it with spark-submit, every thing is ok, **but** in IDE, I can not run the job. There isn't any errors in output but I think Executors are created and killed repeatedly and this **infinite loop** continue until I kill the job. Part of the job's output is given below.

So, my question is What is the problem and how can I fix that? 
(OS in Cluster machines=ubuntu,OS in remote machine=Windows,Hadoop version in all machines=2.7.6,spark version in all machines=2.3). Also, I can see Spark,hadoop,HDFS UIs in my remote machine

```
INFO  SparkContext:54 - Submitted application: Spark SQL examples
INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: myuser
INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: myuser
INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to: 
INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to: 
INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(myuser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(myuser); groups with modify permissions: Set()
INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 54185.
INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering MapOutputTracker
INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering BlockManagerMaster
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
INFO  DiskBlockManager:54 - Created local directory at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-bfdb28f1-2d03-4799-927a-5aba5bdc4eb5
INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore started with capacity 1989.6 MB
INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
INFO  log:192 - Logging initialized @17992ms
INFO  Server:346 - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
INFO  Server:414 - Started @18089ms
INFO  AbstractConnector:278 - Started ServerConnector@53325049{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@28a0fd6c{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c48c0c0{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@10c8f62{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@25f7391e{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f23a3a0{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5ab14cb9{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5fb97279{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@31024624{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@25bcd0c7{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@32cb636e{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63cd604c{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40dd3977{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a4e343{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6a1d204a{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@62dae245{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4b6579e8{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6fff253c{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6c6357f9{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@591e58fa{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3954d008{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2f94c4db{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@669513d8{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a1d593e{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@285d851a{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@314b8f2d{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  SparkUI:54 - Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://12J623S.mydomain.com:4040
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Connecting to master spark://176.14.100.110:7077...
INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /176.14.100.110:7077 after 35 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20180828223816-0001
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/0 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.125-42178 (176.14.100.125:42178) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/0 on hostPort 176.14.100.125:42178 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/1 on worker-20180828222717-176.14.100.117-37298 (176.14.100.117:37298) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/1 on hostPort 176.14.100.117:37298 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/2 on worker-20180828222629-176.14.100.120-45386 (176.14.100.120:45386) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/2 on hostPort 176.14.100.120:45386 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/3 on worker-20180828222629-176.14.100.121-43346 (176.14.100.121:43346) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/3 on hostPort 176.14.100.121:43346 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/4 on worker-20180828222630-176.14.100.119-41350 (176.14.100.119:41350) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/4 on hostPort 176.14.100.119:41350 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/5 on worker-20180828222636-176.14.100.114-45065 (176.14.100.114:45065) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/5 on hostPort 176.14.100.114:45065 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/6 on worker-20180828222718-176.14.100.115-42930 (176.14.100.115:42930) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/6 on hostPort 176.14.100.115:42930 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/7 on worker-20180828222636-176.14.100.112-35929 (176.14.100.112:35929) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/7 on hostPort 176.14.100.112:35929 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/8 on worker-20180828222718-176.14.100.118-42680 (176.14.100.118:42680) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/8 on hostPort 176.14.100.118:42680 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/9 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.124-43803 (176.14.100.124:43803) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/9 on hostPort 176.14.100.124:43803 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/10 on worker-20180828222718-176.14.100.116-41357 (176.14.100.116:41357) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/10 on hostPort 176.14.100.116:41357 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/11 on worker-20180828222636-176.14.100.113-43664 (176.14.100.113:43664) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/11 on hostPort 176.14.100.113:43664 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/12 on worker-20180828222629-176.14.100.122-34652 (176.14.100.122:34652) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/12 on hostPort 176.14.100.122:34652 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/13 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.123-37211 (176.14.100.123:37211) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/13 on hostPort 176.14.100.123:37211 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/14 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.126-42803 (176.14.100.126:42803) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/14 on hostPort 176.14.100.126:42803 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/2 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/0 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/7 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/9 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/1 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/3 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/13 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/8 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/6 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/14 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/5 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/11 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/4 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/12 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/10 is now RUNNING
INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54207.
INFO  NettyBlockTransferService:54 - Server created on 12J623S.mydomain.com:54207
INFO  BlockManager:54 - Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 12J623S.mydomain.com, 54207, None)
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Registering block manager 12J623S.mydomain.com:54207 with 1989.6 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 12J623S.mydomain.com, 54207, None)
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 12J623S.mydomain.com, 54207, None)
INFO  BlockManager:54 - Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 12J623S.mydomain.com, 54207, None)
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7dc51783{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
INFO  SharedState:54 - Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/C:/Users/myuser/eclipse-workspace/Test/spark-warehouse/').
INFO  SharedState:54 - Warehouse path is 'file:/C:/Users/myuser/eclipse-workspace/test/spark-warehouse/'.
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7a94b64e{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3e6f3bae{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@34237b90{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1d01dfa5{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@759d81f3{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
INFO  StateStoreCoordinatorRef:54 - Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/13 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/13 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/15 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.123-37211 (176.14.100.123:37211) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/15 on hostPort 176.14.100.123:37211 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/15 is now RUNNING
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 13 requested
INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 13
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 13 from BlockManagerMaster.
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/11 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/11 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/16 on worker-20180828222636-176.14.100.113-43664 (176.14.100.113:43664) with 12 core(s)
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 11 requested
INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 11
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 11 from BlockManagerMaster.
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/16 on hostPort 176.14.100.113:43664 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/7 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/7 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/17 on worker-20180828222636-176.14.100.112-35929 (176.14.100.112:35929) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/17 on hostPort 176.14.100.112:35929 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/16 is now RUNNING
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 7 requested
INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 7
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/17 is now RUNNING
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 7 from BlockManagerMaster.
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/5 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/5 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/18 on worker-20180828222636-176.14.100.114-45065 (176.14.100.114:45065) with 12 core(s)
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 5 from BlockManagerMaster.
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/18 on hostPort 176.14.100.114:45065 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/18 is now RUNNING
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 5 requested
INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 5
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/9 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/9 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/19 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.124-43803 (176.14.100.124:43803) with 12 core(s)
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 9 from BlockManagerMaster.
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 9 requested
INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/19 on hostPort 176.14.100.124:43803 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/19 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/14 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/14 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 14 requested
INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 14
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 14 from BlockManagerMaster.
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/20 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.126-42803 (176.14.100.126:42803) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/20 on hostPort 176.14.100.126:42803 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/20 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/0 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor added: app-20180828223816-0001/21 on worker-20180828221707-176.14.100.125-42178 (176.14.100.125:42178) with 12 core(s)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Granted executor ID app-20180828223816-0001/21 on hostPort 176.14.100.125:42178 with 12 core(s), 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 0 requested
INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/21 is now RUNNING
INFO  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:54 - Executor updated: app-20180828223816-0001/10 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Executor app-20180828223816-0001/10 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - Removal of executor 10 requested
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I just should set spark.driver.host option as mentioned in [this link](https://blogs.perficient.com/2015/06/04/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-spark-application-in-the-cluster/). Also if your program has some external jar files you should use setJar method and set path to those jar files as mentioned in that link.